# (click) event to button is not workimg

Tags: angular

login.component.html code

```
<div>
<input type="text" [ngmodel]="username">
<input type="text" [ngmodel]="password">
<button type="submit" (click)="logincheck()">
</div>
```

When I am saving this HTML page, the ngmodel and click event disappear from the page and the page is automatically converted to normal HTML page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<div>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<button type="submit" ></div>
</body>
<html>
```

Why the `ngmodel` and click event are missed in the `login.component.html` page?

Comment: Have you tried closing the button tag? `<button type="submit" (click)="logincheck()">Login</button>`

Comment: they are note missing.. angular have compilation step between real `browser dom rendering` and what you have really write on your `login.template.html`. At the same time, and after having bind all the stuff, angular remove her syntax to clean the code.

Comment: typo should be `ngModel` instead of `ngmodel`

Comment: Did you run a build between saving the file and loading the file in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax for ngmodel is [(ngModel)].

(click) handler is registered behind the scenes, it will not be shown in the html.

Comment: incorrect, he can specifiy if he wants his ngModel to be read only or read & write, when using the [()] you're basically specifying the value and the (change) event.

Answer (score 0):

Button needs to be type “button” not “submit”. Submit messes up click handling.

Answer (score 0):

the type of your button is a submit, so when you click on it is triggering the onSubmit() event which is not existing in your case, so you'll have to choose between submitting your form or, using a click event on a normal button, below is a clear example on how the two approaches work :

Approach 1 : **using a form submission**

```
<form   (ngSubmit)="logincheck(f)" #f="ngForm">
   <input type="text" [ngModel]="username">
   <input type="text" [ngModel]="password">
   <button type="submit">
</form>
```

Approach 2 : **using a simple click event**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" [ngModel]="username">
    <input type="text" [ngModel]="password">
    <button type="button" (click)="logincheck()">
</div>
```